# how can I manage gaps in css subgrids?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I've made a custom CSS Grid in React, but I think the main issue could be resolved only with CSS.
so there is my Grid component :

```
import React, { ReactNode, useCallback, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";
import * as CSS from "csstype";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";
interface GridProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  columns?: number | CSS.Property.GridTemplateColumns;
  smallScreenColumns?: number | CSS.Property.GridTemplateColumns;
  rows?: number | CSS.Property.GridTemplateColumns;
  rowGap?: string;
  columnGap?: string;
  className?: string;
  uniqueClass?: string;
}
interface Gap {
  [key: string]: string;
}

const toCssProperty = (property: string) => {
  return property.replace(/([A-Z])/g, (match) => `-${match.toLowerCase()}`);
};
const stylesToCSS = (styles: React.CSSProperties) =>
  Object.entries(styles)
    .map(([key, value]) => `${toCssProperty(key)}:${value};`)
    .join("");

const Grid = ({
  children,
  className,
  style,
  columns,
  smallScreenColumns,
  rows,
  rowGap,
  columnGap,
  uniqueClass
}: GridProps) => {
  // Check screen size to manage responsive
  const hasWideScreen = useMediaQuery({
    query: `(min-width: 796px)`
  });
  // Generate unique className
  const uniqueClassName: string = useMemo(
    () => uniqueClass || `grid-${uuidv4().slice(0, 8)}`,
    [uniqueClass]
  );

  // Get gap from props
  const getGap = useCallback((g?: string) => {
    const gaps: Gap[] = [
      { xs: "0.625rem" },
      { s: "0.750rem" },
      { m: "0.875rem" },
      { l: "1rem" },
      { xl: "1.125rem" },
      { xxl: "1.25rem" }
    ];
    if (g) {
      const selectedGap = gaps.find((gap) => gap[g]);
      return selectedGap ? selectedGap[g] : "0";
    }
    return "0";
  }, []);

  const getColumnPattern = useCallback(() => {
    if (!hasWideScreen) {
      return smallScreenColumns || "1fr";
    }
    return columns || "auto";
  }, [columns, hasWideScreen, smallScreenColumns]);
  // Defines grid CSS properties
  const styles: React.CSSProperties = useMemo(
    () => ({
      display: "grid",
      gridTemplateColumns: getColumnPattern(),
      gridTemplateRows: rows || "auto",
      columnGap: getGap(columnGap),
      rowGap: getGap(rowGap),
      ...style
    }),
    [columnGap, getColumnPattern, getGap, rowGap, rows, style]
  );
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const hasClassNameCreated = useCallback(() => {
    const documentStyles = document.head.getElementsByTagName("style");
    for (let i = 0; i < documentStyles.length; i += 1) {
      if (documentStyles[i].innerText?.includes(uniqueClassName)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }, [uniqueClassName]);

  // Add custom <style> sheet in <head>
  useEffect(() => {
    const styleElement = document.createElement("style");
    if (!hasClassNameCreated()) {
      styleElement.innerHTML = `.${uniqueClassName} {${stylesToCSS(styles)}}`;
      document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
    }
    return () => {
      if (!uniqueClass) {
        document.head.removeChild(styleElement);
      }
    };
  }, [hasClassNameCreated, styles, uniqueClass, uniqueClassName]);

  return (
    <div className={`${uniqueClassName}${className ? " " + className : ""}`}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Grid;
```

And there is an example of how I use it :

```
import "./styles.css";
import Grid from "./grid";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Grid
        columns="7fr 26fr 11fr"
        smallScreenColumns="7fr 26fr 11fr"
        columnGap="l"
      >
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", height: "50%" }}>test</div>
        <Grid columns="1fr" smallScreenColumns="1fr" rowGap="l" columnGap="l">
          <Grid
            columns="1fr"
            smallScreenColumns="5fr 2fr"
            rowGap="l"
            columnGap="l"
          >
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
            <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          </Grid>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray" }}>test</div>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          columns="subgrid"
          smallScreenColumns="subgrid"
          rowGap="l"
          columnGap="l"
        >
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", height: "fit-content" }}>
            test
          </div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", height: "fit-content" }}>
            test
          </div>
          <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", height: "fit-content" }}>
            test
          </div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

It looks like this :
[image: this]

My question is : What can I do to make the right column vertical gaps smaller (to match with all other gaps) ?

I set the height to "fit-content" so the block doesn't take more space than it needs. If I remove this height property, gaps are ok

here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-khayyam-lxxkec?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1835
Thanks

Comment: Try setting `grid-template-rows: repeat(3, min-content)` for the right column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is adding a class to last column in which you want to have the same space as in others and adding these styles:

```
.last-row{
  display: grid;
  height: fit-content;
  grid-gap: 16px;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-glade-3y7ddf)

Edit: Just try make the app recompile in case you dont see the changes